# @android Resource IDs

Tags: android, listview

In Android layout files, I see the following attribute in a ListView widget:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

How can I access that `ID` inside the Java program with something like the following (which doesn't work)

```
ListView myLV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `ListView myLV = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);` for getting reference to ListView if you have added `ListView`  as  `android:id="@android:id/list"` in xml

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you have set `@android:id/list` id in layout, but trying to find `R.id.list` where `R` is resources class from **your** project

So you got two ways to resolve this problem:

1. Change id in layout to `"@+id/list`
2. Or change id in code to `android.R.id.list`

Answer (score -3):

Try to change first line to something like this:

```
android:id="@+id/list"
```

Comment: That's not an answer, it's a statement.  Please don't just give a line of XML with no explanation.